# My package does not show on search results, even if I can use it with composer command

Tags: php, github, composer-php, packagist

Yesterday, I pushed my code to github. I also wanted to publish it for composer, but I found a problem.
First, I linked my packagist account with github account. Later, I created a package based on github repo. From now on, if I use code in composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "mbajda/yahoo-weather": "dev-master"
}
```

I can use that dependency. But when I open Packagist page and search for that dependency, I get 'no packages found' text. What could go wrong? It’s not a private package.

My [`composer.json`](https://github.com/mbajda/yahoo-weather/blob/master/composer.json):

```
{
    "name": "mbajda/yahoo-weather",
    "description": "Yahoo Weather API PHP Implementation",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "keywords": ["api", "yahoo", "yahoo-weather", "weather"],
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "YahooWeather\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which keywords did you use for searching?

Comment: `yahoo-weather` and `weather`. Also tried to use my vendor name 'mbajda', but that failed too.

Comment: You can try to open an issue on https://github.com/composer/packagist/issues or otherwise try to get in touch with https://github.com/Seldaek. If you appreciate his help, maybe also consider thanking him by ordering him something from his Amazon wishlist: http://seld.be/wishlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with Packagist, which has been solved today.